# django AWS S3 download optimisation

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I work on some django + DRF project, that has application for media files upload to and download from AWS S3 (application is something like proxy, using to not access frontend to download images directly from AWS S3). I noticed, that my download requests work not so fast (500ms +/- 100ms), and in production it probably will be a problem, so my question is following: `"Is there a way to make these requests faster or separate download logic to some async microservice or multiprocess task? What is the best practice?"`

Service, that download images for me in current project state (for context):

```py
# media_app/services/download/image.py
class ImageDownloadService(FileDownloadServiceBase):
    model = Image


# media_app/services/download/base.py
class FileDownloadServiceBase:
    model = ...

    def __init__(self, instance: str) -> None:
        self.instance = instance

    def _get_file(self, presigned_url):
        response = requests.get(url=presigned_url, stream=True)
        return response

    def download(self) -> Tuple[file_data, status_code]:
        s3 = boto3.resource(
            service_name='s3',
            aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            region_name=settings.AWS_S3_REGION_NAME,
        )
        url = s3.meta.client.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod="get_object", ExpiresIn=3600,
            Params={
                "Bucket": settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
                "Key": f'media/public/{self.instance.file_name}',
            },
        )
        response = self._get_file(url)
        return response.content, response.status_code
```

Comment: The main concern is that Django (+gunicorn) will not be able to handle a large amount of file download requests (1000 requests per second, for example). If I'm wrong, let me know it.

Comment: For more secure I will add max file size limit and request per second limit, but, as for me, it won't make a big difference.